# KendoGrid Excel export all pages with lazy loading

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

My export excel toolbar works great when i don't use `allPages = true`.
with all pages option it doesn't raise any error and do nothing, I figured out this is may caused by lazy loading rows for each page.

I've searched a lot and found nothing for this problem.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {

                            dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                                serverPaging: true,
                                serverSorting: true,
                                serverFiltering: true,
                                requestEnd: function (e) {
                                    showServerMessageInGrid(e);
                                    if (e.response.IsSuccess == false)
                                        this.read();
                                },
                                transport: {
                                    read: {
                                        url: "@Url.Action("AjaxOrderList", "Order")",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        type: "POST"
                                    },
                                    parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                        if (operation == "read") {
                                            return { options: kendo.stringify(options) };

                                        }
                                        if (operation !== "read") {

                                            return {
                                                models: kendo.stringify(options.models),
                                                options: kendo.stringify(options)
                                            };
                                        }

                                    }
                                },
                                batch: true,
                                pageSize: 20,
                                schema: {
                                    data: 'ViewModel',
                                    total: 'TotalCount',
                                    model: {
                                        id: "Id",
                                        fields: {
                                            Id: { width: 90, editable: false },
                                            CityName: { width: 120, editable: false }
                                              }
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                                dataSource: dataSource,
                                toolbar:[{ name: "excel" }],
                                excel: {
                                    fileName: "OrderList.xlsx",                                        
                                    filterable: true,
                                    allPages: true
                                },
                                scrollable:true,
                                pageable: true,
                                selectable: true,
                                resizable: true,
                                filterable: true,
                                sortable: true,
                                columns: [
                                    { field: "Id",  width: "90px", editable: false, filterable: filterableNumeric() },
                                    { field: "CityName",  width: "120px", editable: false }
                                                            ],
                                editable: "inline",
                                }
                            });
                        });
</script>
```

Any idea how can i export all pages with lazy loading?

Comment: May not be related, but why are you re-reading the dataSource on requestEnd?  And by "do nothing" do you really mean it does nothing or that no results are returned...what do devtools show as the request/response?  What is the server implementation of AjaxOrderList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem. 
It was `MaxJsonLength` because  the result of my action was `new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(_orderList).`

I solved it by `Int32.MaxValue()`

```
  var json = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            json.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; 
            var jsonResult = json.Serialize(_orderList);
            return jsonResult;
```